# WPF Video Transport Control

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

I am relatively new to custom controls (writing control from scratch in code - not merely styling existing controls). I am having a go at replicating the YouTube video control, you know the one...

[image]

To start with I want to develop the "timeline" (the transparent grey bar, which displays the current position of the video and allows the user to drag to change position). With the preview panel and all the rest coming later on...

I currently have the control partially rendered and the hover animations and scale working very well...

[image]

However, I am struggling to write the correct code to allow me to drag the "thumb". When I try and handle my left click on the `Ellipse` that is representing my thumb, the leave event of the containing `Canvas` fires, in accordance with the WPF documentation, so no complaints, I just don;t know how to achieve what I want and indeed if what I have done already is the correct approach.

The code:

```
[ToolboxItem(true)]
[DisplayName("VideoTimeline")]
[Description("Controls which allows the user navigate video media. In addition is can display a " +
    "waveform repesenting the audio channels for the loaded video media.")]
//[TemplatePart(Name = "PART_ThumbCanvas", Type = typeof(Canvas))]
[TemplatePart(Name = "PART_TimelineCanvas", Type = typeof(Canvas))]
[TemplatePart(Name = "PART_WaveformCanvas", Type = typeof(Canvas))]
[TemplatePart(Name = "PART_PreviewCanvas", Type = typeof(Canvas))]
[TemplatePart(Name = "PART_Thumb", Type = typeof(Ellipse))] // Is this the right thing to be doing? 
public class VideoTimeline : Control
{
    private Canvas thumbCanvas;
    private Canvas timelineCanvas;
    private Canvas waveformCanvas;
    private Canvas previewCanvas;

    private Rectangle timelineOuterBox = new Rectangle();
    private Rectangle timelineProgressBox = new Rectangle();
    private Rectangle timelineSelectionBox = new Rectangle();

    private Ellipse timelineThumb = new Ellipse();
    private Path previewWindow = new Path();

    private Point mouseDownPosition;
    private Point currentMousePosition;

    private const int TIMELINE_ANIMATION_DURATION = 400;
    private const string HIGHLIGHT_FILL = "#878787";

    private double __timelineWidth;

    #region Initialization.
    static VideoTimeline()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(VideoTimeline),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(VideoTimeline)));
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        //thumbCanvas = GetTemplateChild("PART_ThumbCanvas") as Canvas;
        //thumbCanvas.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
        //thumbCanvas.Children.Add(timelineThumb);

        timelineThumb = EnforceInstance<Ellipse>("PART_Thumb");
        timelineThumb.MouseLeftButtonDown -= TimelineThumb_MouseLeftButtonDown;
        timelineThumb.MouseLeftButtonDown += TimelineThumb_MouseLeftButtonDown;

        timelineCanvas = GetTemplateChild("PART_TimelineCanvas") as Canvas;
        timelineCanvas.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
        timelineCanvas.Children.Add(timelineOuterBox);
        timelineCanvas.Children.Add(timelineSelectionBox);
        timelineCanvas.Children.Add(timelineProgressBox);
        timelineCanvas.Children.Add(timelineThumb);

        previewCanvas = GetTemplateChild("PART_PreviewCanvas") as Canvas;
        previewCanvas.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
        previewCanvas.Children.Add(previewWindow);


    }

    private T EnforceInstance<T>(string partName) where T : FrameworkElement, new()
    {
        return GetTemplateChild(partName) as T ?? new T();
    }

    protected override void OnTemplateChanged(ControlTemplate oldTemplate, ControlTemplate newTemplate)
    {
        base.OnTemplateChanged(oldTemplate, newTemplate);

        if (timelineCanvas != null)
            timelineCanvas.Children.Clear();

        SetDefaultMeasurements();
    }
    #endregion // Initialization.

    #region Event Overrides.
    protected override void OnRenderSizeChanged(SizeChangedInfo sizeInfo)
    {
        base.OnRenderSizeChanged(sizeInfo);
        //UpdateWaveformCacheScaling();
        SetDefaultMeasurements();
        UpdateAllRegions();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);

        Canvas c = e.OriginalSource as Canvas;
        if (c == null)
            c = Utils.FindParent<Canvas>(e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement);

        if (c != null)
        {
            CaptureMouse();
            mouseDownPosition = e.GetPosition(c);
            if (c.Name == "PART_TimelineCanvas")
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("OnMouseLeftDown over TimeLine");
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(e);
        ReleaseMouseCapture();

    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
        currentMousePosition = e.GetPosition(thumbCanvas);

        if (Mouse.Captured == null)
        {
            Canvas c = e.OriginalSource as Canvas;
            if (c == null)
                c = Utils.FindParent<Canvas>(e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement);
        }
    }
    #endregion // Event Overrides.

    #region Drawing Methods and Events.
    private void UpdateAllRegions()
    {
        UpdateTimelineCanvas();
    }

    private void UpdateTimelineCanvas()
    {
        if (timelineCanvas == null)
            return;

        SetDefaultMeasurements();

        // Bounding timeline box.
        timelineOuterBox.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(
            (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#878787")) { Opacity = 0.25 };
        timelineOuterBox.StrokeThickness = 0.0;
        timelineOuterBox.Width = __timelineWidth;
        timelineOuterBox.Height = TimelineThickness;
        timelineOuterBox.Margin = new Thickness(TimelineExpansionFactor * TimelineThickness,
            (timelineCanvas.RenderSize.Height - TimelineThickness) / 2, 0, 0);
        timelineOuterBox.SnapsToDevicePixels = true;

        // Selection timeline box.
        timelineSelectionBox.Fill = TimelineSelectionBrush;
        timelineSelectionBox.Width = 0.0;
        timelineSelectionBox.Height = TimelineThickness;
        timelineSelectionBox.Margin = new Thickness(TimelineExpansionFactor * TimelineThickness,
            (timelineCanvas.RenderSize.Height - TimelineThickness) / 2, 0, 0);
        timelineSelectionBox.SnapsToDevicePixels = true;

        // Progress timeline box.
        timelineProgressBox.Fill = TimelineProgressBrush;
        timelineProgressBox.StrokeThickness = 0.0;
        timelineProgressBox.Width = 0.0;
        timelineProgressBox.Height = TimelineThickness;
        timelineProgressBox.Margin = new Thickness(TimelineExpansionFactor * TimelineThickness,
            (timelineCanvas.RenderSize.Height - TimelineThickness) / 2, 0, 0);
        timelineProgressBox.SnapsToDevicePixels = true;

        // Animation and selection.
        timelineCanvas.MouseEnter -= TimelineCanvas_MouseEnter;
        timelineCanvas.MouseEnter += TimelineCanvas_MouseEnter;

        timelineCanvas.MouseLeave -= TimelineCanvas_MouseLeave;
        timelineCanvas.MouseLeave += TimelineCanvas_MouseLeave;

        timelineCanvas.MouseMove -= TimelineCanvas_MouseMove;
        timelineCanvas.MouseMove += TimelineCanvas_MouseMove;

        timelineCanvas.MouseDown -= TimelineCanvas_MouseDown;
        timelineCanvas.MouseDown += TimelineCanvas_MouseDown;

        // The draggable thumb.
        timelineThumb.Fill = TimelineThumbBrush;
        //timelineThumb.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        //timelineThumb.StrokeThickness = 0.5;
        timelineThumb.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        timelineThumb.Height = timelineThumb.Width = 0.0;
        timelineThumb.Margin = new Thickness(TimelineExpansionFactor * TimelineThickness, 
            timelineCanvas.RenderSize.Height / 2, 0, 0);
        timelineThumb.SnapsToDevicePixels = true;

        timelineThumb.MouseLeftButtonDown -= TimelineThumb_MouseLeftButtonDown;
        timelineThumb.MouseLeftButtonDown += TimelineThumb_MouseLeftButtonDown;

        timelineThumb.MouseLeftButtonUp -= TimelineThumb_MouseLeftButtonUp;
        timelineThumb.MouseLeftButtonUp += TimelineThumb_MouseLeftButtonUp;

        // Preview window.
    }

    private void TimelineCanvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("POON");
    }

    private void SetDefaultMeasurements()
    {
        if (timelineCanvas != null)
            __timelineWidth = timelineCanvas.RenderSize.Width - 2 * 2 * TimelineThickness;
    }

    private void TimelineCanvas_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        timelineThumb.ResetAnimation(Ellipse.WidthProperty, Ellipse.HeightProperty);
        timelineProgressBox.ResetAnimation(Rectangle.HeightProperty, Rectangle.MarginProperty);
        timelineSelectionBox.ResetAnimation(Rectangle.HeightProperty, Rectangle.MarginProperty);
        timelineOuterBox.ResetAnimation(Rectangle.HeightProperty, Rectangle.MarginProperty);

        CircleEase easing = new CircleEase();
        easing.EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut;

        // Thumb animation.
        Thickness margin = new Thickness(0, 
            (timelineCanvas.RenderSize.Height - 2 * TimelineExpansionFactor * TimelineThickness) / 2, 0, 0);
        EllpiseDiameterAnimation(timelineThumb, TimelineThickness * TimelineExpansionFactor * 2, margin, easing);

        // Timeline animation.
        margin = new Thickness(TimelineExpansionFactor * TimelineThickness,
            (timelineCanvas.RenderSize.Height - (TimelineThickness * TimelineExpansionFactor)) / 2, 0, 0);
        TimelineHeightAnimation(timelineProgressBox, TimelineThickness * TimelineExpansionFactor, margin, easing);
        TimelineHeightAnimation(timelineSelectionBox, TimelineThickness * TimelineExpansionFactor, margin, easing);
        TimelineHeightAnimation(timelineOuterBox, TimelineThickness * TimelineExpansionFactor, margin, easing);

        double selectionWidth = (currentMousePosition.X / RenderSize.Width) * timelineOuterBox.Width;
        timelineSelectionBox.Width = selectionWidth;

        Trace.WriteLine("MouseENTER Canvas");
    }

    private void TimelineCanvas_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        timelineThumb.ResetAnimation(Ellipse.WidthProperty, Ellipse.HeightProperty);
        timelineProgressBox.ResetAnimation(Rectangle.HeightProperty, Rectangle.MarginProperty);
        timelineSelectionBox.ResetAnimation(Rectangle.HeightProperty, Rectangle.MarginProperty);
        timelineOuterBox.ResetAnimation(Rectangle.HeightProperty, Rectangle.MarginProperty);

        CircleEase easing = new CircleEase();
        easing.EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut;

        // Thumb animation.
        Thickness margin = new Thickness(TimelineExpansionFactor * TimelineThickness, timelineCanvas.RenderSize.Height / 2, 0, 0);
        EllpiseDiameterAnimation(timelineThumb, 0.0, margin, easing);

        // Timeline animation.
        margin = new Thickness(TimelineExpansionFactor * TimelineThickness,
            (timelineCanvas.RenderSize.Height - TimelineThickness) / 2, 0, 0);
        TimelineHeightAnimation(timelineProgressBox, TimelineThickness, margin, easing);
        TimelineHeightAnimation(timelineSelectionBox, TimelineThickness, margin, easing);
        TimelineHeightAnimation(timelineOuterBox, TimelineThickness, margin, easing);

        if (!isDraggingThumb)
            timelineSelectionBox.Width = 0.0;

        Trace.WriteLine("MouseLeave Canvas");
    }

    private void TimelineCanvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point relativePosition = e.GetPosition(timelineOuterBox);
        double selectionWidth = (relativePosition.X / timelineOuterBox.Width) * timelineOuterBox.Width;
        timelineSelectionBox.Width = selectionWidth.Clamp(0.0, timelineOuterBox.Width);

        if (isDraggingThumb)
        {
            timelineProgressBox.Width = timelineSelectionBox.Width;
            Thickness thumbMargin = new Thickness(TimelineExpansionFactor * TimelineThickness,
                (timelineCanvas.RenderSize.Height - (TimelineThickness * TimelineExpansionFactor)) / 2, 0, 0);
            timelineThumb.Margin = thumbMargin;

        }
    }

    private bool isDraggingThumb = false;

    private void TimelineThumb_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        CaptureMouse();
        isDraggingThumb = true;
        Trace.WriteLine("Dragging Thumb");
    }

    private void TimelineThumb_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ReleaseMouseCapture();
        isDraggingThumb = false;
        Trace.WriteLine("STOPPED Dragging Thumb");
    }

    #endregion // Drawing Methods and Events.

    #region Animation Methods.
    private void EllpiseDiameterAnimation(Ellipse ellipse, double diameter, Thickness margin, IEasingFunction easing)
    {
        AnimationTimeline widthAnimation = ShapeWidthAnimation(ellipse, diameter, easing);
        AnimationTimeline heightAnimation = ShapeHeightAnimation(ellipse, diameter, easing);
        AnimationTimeline marginAnimation = ShapeMarginAnimation(ellipse, margin, easing);

        Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
        storyboard.Children.Add(widthAnimation);
        storyboard.Children.Add(heightAnimation);
        storyboard.Children.Add(marginAnimation);
        storyboard.Begin(this);
    }

    private void TimelineHeightAnimation(Rectangle rectangle, double height, Thickness margin, IEasingFunction easing)
    {
        AnimationTimeline heightAnimation = ShapeHeightAnimation(rectangle, height, easing);
        AnimationTimeline marginAnimation = ShapeMarginAnimation(rectangle, margin, easing);

        Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
        storyboard.Children.Add(marginAnimation);
        storyboard.Children.Add(heightAnimation);
        storyboard.Begin(this);
    }

    private AnimationTimeline ShapeMarginAnimation(Shape shape, Thickness margin, IEasingFunction easing)
    {
        ThicknessAnimation marginAnimation = new ThicknessAnimation(
            margin, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds((TIMELINE_ANIMATION_DURATION)));

        if (easing != null)
            marginAnimation.EasingFunction = easing;

        Storyboard.SetTarget(marginAnimation, shape);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(marginAnimation, new PropertyPath(Rectangle.MarginProperty));

        return marginAnimation;
    }

    private AnimationTimeline ShapeWidthAnimation(Shape shape, double width, IEasingFunction easing)
    {
        DoubleAnimation widthAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(
            width, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(TIMELINE_ANIMATION_DURATION));

        if (easing != null)
            widthAnimation.EasingFunction = easing;

        Storyboard.SetTarget(widthAnimation, shape);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(widthAnimation, new PropertyPath(Shape.WidthProperty));

        return widthAnimation;
    }

    private AnimationTimeline ShapeHeightAnimation(Shape shape, double height, IEasingFunction easing)
    {
        DoubleAnimation heightAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(
            height, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(TIMELINE_ANIMATION_DURATION));

        if (easing != null)
            heightAnimation.EasingFunction = easing;

        Storyboard.SetTarget(heightAnimation, shape);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(heightAnimation, new PropertyPath(Shape.HeightProperty));

        return heightAnimation;
    }
    #endregion // Animation Methods.

    // Lots of DependencyProperties here...
}
```

The XAML style

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MediaControlBuilder">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:VideoTimeline}">
        <Setter Property="TimelineProgressBrush" Value="DarkOrange"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:VideoTimeline}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                       BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                       BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <!--<RowDefinition Height="*"/>-->
                                <!--<RowDefinition Height="15"/>-->
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                                <!--<RowDefinition Height="*"/>-->
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Canvas Name="PART_PreviewCanvas"
                             Grid.Row="0"
                             ClipToBounds="True"/>
                            <Canvas Name="PART_ThumbCanvas"
                             Grid.Row="1"
                             ClipToBounds="True"/>
                            <Canvas Name="PART_TimelineCanvas"
                             Grid.Row="1"
                             ClipToBounds="True"/>
                            <Canvas Name="PART_WaveformCanvas"
                             Grid.Row="1"
                             ClipToBounds="True"/> 
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

My questions are:

1. Is my approach for drawing the draggable thumb correct?
2. How can I actually change the code to get the dragging of my "thumb" to work?

Thanks for your time.

Ps. the GitHub project with the working code is [here](https://github.com/Camuvingian/symmetrical-spork) so you can reproduce the problem I am having. If anyone wants to help me develop this control, that would be awesome!

Pps. I am aware I could override a slider to get my functionality for the "timeline", but this is just the first part of a much more comprehensive control and hence needs to be written from scratch.

Comment: It is not a "timeline", such a gadget is named "transport control".  Helps you to find [stuff like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/custom-transport-controls).  Wrong framework but next ballpark over.

Comment: Thanks for this Hans, this gives me a great avenue for further investigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure but I think that can resolve your problem :

```
    private void TimelineCanvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point relativePosition = e.GetPosition(timelineOuterBox);
        double selectionWidth = (relativePosition.X / timelineOuterBox.Width) * timelineOuterBox.Width;
        timelineSelectionBox.Width = selectionWidth.Clamp(0.0, timelineOuterBox.Width);

        if (isDraggingThumb)
        {
            timelineProgressBox.Width = timelineSelectionBox.Width;
            //Thickness thumbMargin = new Thickness(TimelineThickness * TimelineExpansionFactor,
            //  (timelineCanvas.RenderSize.Height - (TimelineThickness * TimelineExpansionFactor)) / 2, 0, 0);
            //timelineThumb.Margin = thumbMargin;
            Canvas.SetLeft(timelineThumb, timelineProgressBox.Width);
        }
    }

    private bool isDraggingThumb = false;       

    private void TimelineThumb_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        //CaptureMouse();
        isDraggingThumb = true;
        Trace.WriteLine("Dragging Thumb");
    }

    private void TimelineThumb_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        //ReleaseMouseCapture();
        isDraggingThumb = false;
        Trace.WriteLine("STOPPED Dragging Thumb");
    }
```

You can stop the bubbling by handling the event args, and the leave event won't be fired.

To change the position of the thumb, you have to set the Left attached property of the Canvas.

Additionnaly you will have to reset isdraggingThumb :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when an unhandled MouseLeftButtonUp routed event reaches an element in 
    /// its route that is derived from this class. Implement this method to add class 
    /// handling for this event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">The MouseButtonEventArgs that contains the event data. The event 
    /// data reports that the left mouse button was released.</param>
    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        isDraggingThumb = false;
```

Comment: This answer was the most helpful, but the bounty was auto-awarded. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

When creating new custom controls you should not "write control from scratch in code". 
Better is to base your new implementation of an existing control. In your case you want to create a custom slider control so your custom control could inherit from `Slider` leveraging existing functionality like thumb dragging logic and Start, End, Value properties.

When extending an existing control you start with original control's default template, it can be obtained with VS. A slider will have an element that you should be particularly interested in:

```
<Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Column="1">
    <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
        <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.DecreaseLarge}" Style="{StaticResource RepeatButtonTransparent}"/>
    </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
    <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
        <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.IncreaseLarge}" Style="{StaticResource RepeatButtonTransparent}"/>
    </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
    <Track.Thumb>
        <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Focusable="False" Height="11" OverridesDefaultStyle="True" Template="{StaticResource SliderThumbVerticalDefault}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="18"/>
    </Track.Thumb>
</Track>
```

By using the required elements in the template your base control will take care of all basic slider capabilities. Starting from this, you can alter the base control functionality, style the slider parts the way you want and add any new functionality.

If you don't want to expose `Slider` properties that are not applicable for your Timeline control, like `Minimum`, just use a `Slider` control in your template.

Comment: No, I want everything that the YouTube media control does. This is merely the first step in that goal. I need a new control written from scratch for this, not a compound user control written in XAML overriding and styling existing controls. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your question is focused on the timeline slider. There is no need to create your own. Just use the [Slider control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.slider(v=vs.110).aspx). You can restyle to make the fill red and the remaining semi-transparent. Then you can bind the Value to the Position of the MediaElement control and the Maximum of the Slider to the Duration.

```xml
<Slider Value="{Binding Position.Milliseconds, ElementName=MediaPlayer}" 
        Maximum="{Binding Duration.TimeSpan.Milliseconds, , ElementName=MediaPlayer}"
        Style="{StaticResource YouTubeSliderStyle}" />
```

When the value changes you can update the Position of the MediaElement. You only want to do this when the user changes the value (not when it changes due to Position updating). To accomplish this you can listen to then mousedown/up and keydown/up events. During these events you can then (un)subscribe to the ValueChanged event and update the position.

```cs
private void UpdatePosition(long time)
{
    MediaPlayer.Position = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(time);
}
```

**Update**: Ways to show/hide the thumb.
You can show or hide the thumb two ways. The first is to create anew Slider control and show/hide the thumb when the mouse is over.

```
class YouTubeSlider : Slider
{
    private Thumb _thumb;

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        _thumb = (Thumb)GetTemplateChild("Thumb");
        _thumb.Opacity = 0;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseEnter(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseEnter(e);
        _thumb.Opacity = 1;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        _thumb.Opacity = 0;
    }
}
```

The second is to handle it within the style of the control. (some parts have been removed for brevity)

```xml
<ControlTemplate x:Key="SliderHorizontal" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <!-- Elements -->
                <Track.Thumb>
                    <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Opacity="0" Focusable="False" Height="18" OverridesDefaultStyle="True" Template="{StaticResource SliderThumbHorizontalDefault}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="11"/>
                </Track.Thumb>
    <!-- closing tags -->
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <!-- missing triggers -->
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="Thumb" Value="1"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Shawn, but as I have said in my comment to Novitchi S above, I _want_ to write the control from scratch, and although you are correct for a slider control, I am going to be adding all of the other components to this control (and more). I am aware that I could merely style a slider but this is not what I want to do in this case. I perhaps should make this clearer in the question. Thanks again...

Comment: Why is writing your own Slider a requirement? I understand adding the other transport controls, but why write a custom Slider?

Comment: Perhaps what I am doing it overkill, but I want animation on the slider control, I perhaps could have a `TemplatedPart` that was a `Slider` and go from there, but a slider is so basic in terms of functionality, I thought I'd just write my own.

Comment: What type of animation are you looking for?

Comment: The animation that is shown in the attached GIF file. I want the slider bar to expand dynamically and the thumb to disappear when the mouse is not over the slider et al.

Comment: You can accomplish that with the Slider control. I've updated my answer to include two ways

Comment: Looked at your video again and noticed the grey part growing shrinking as well. This can be accomplished the same way as I did with the thumb