# Is it possible to have multiple backgrounds for Slider Trackbar Control in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, slider

I am trying to create a multi color slider. I have three colors Red,Green,Blue.
I am trying to set the color of 0-33 Red, 34-66 Green, 67-100 Blue of the slider Track bar

I am confused on how to do this.

I was able to set the background of slider but I am getting a gradient I want something similar to this but not a gradient just solid colors.

```
var brush = new LinearGradientBrush(new GradientStopCollection() { 
                new GradientStop(Colors.Red, 0.0),
                new GradientStop(Colors.Blue, 0.3),
                new GradientStop(Colors.Green, 0.6),
            });
            TestBar.Background = brush;
```

I am trying to do something dynamic
Like if I have a class like this

```
class SomeObject {
    public int From;
    public int To;
    public string Color;
}
```

I can change the track bars colors without any issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF Video Transport Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43989388/wpf-video-transport-control)

Comment: Actually no I just gave an example of Youtube color scheme my trackbar should have different colors on different ranges 1-10 Yellow, 11-82 Red, 83-100 Green and so on

Comment: "if I have a class like this... I can change the track bars colors without any issue.". Then you're good. I don't know how you'd use a class like that to do that, but it sounds like you do, so what's your question? What does "something dynamic" mean? Anything dynamic in particular, or just any old thing that's dynamic? And what does "dynamic" mean to you anyway? Maybe you could draw a crude picture of what you want in MS Paint, and add that to your question.

Comment: If you take a look at the template: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/slider-styles-and-templates  Note that what looks like the one track that the thumb sits on top of is actually two repeatbuttons. Make then transparent and set the background of the track to your gradient. There will likely be side effects you need to resolve though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to do what I think you want here, using a full custom control.  [The code is on GitHub](https://github.com/rich-newman/ColorSlider).  There may be easier ways to do this, but because you want the Background of the control split into three and colored I thought the logical thing to do was to put three Rectangles into the Control Template and color them.

[image]

The code contains a ColorSlider control, with dependency properties Color1, Color2, Color3 (of type Brush) for the three colors, and Width1, Width2, Width3 (doubles) for the three widths.

To do this we set up a ColorSlider class which registers the dependency properties (excerpt):

```
public class ColorSlider : Slider
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty Width1Property = DependencyProperty.Register("Width1", typeof(double), typeof(ColorSlider), new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0));
    [TypeConverter(typeof(LengthConverter))]
    public double Width1
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(Width1Property); }
        set { SetValue(Width1Property, value); }
    }
```

We need a copy of the Slider Control Template targetting the ColorSlider and then with a Stackpanel in its grid as below (excerpt clearly):

```
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Panel.ZIndex="-1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Color1}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width1}" />
                    <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Color2}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width2}" />
                    <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Color3}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width3}" />
                </StackPanel>
```

Now we can create a color slider and set these properties:

```
<local:ColorSlider x:Name="MyColorSlider" Template="{DynamicResource ColorSliderControlTemplate}" Width="200" Height="50"
Color1="Red" Color2="Green" Color3="Blue" Width1="68" Width2="66" Width3="66"></local:ColorSlider>
```

And we can set them dynamically from code:

```
            MyColorSlider.Width3 = 20;
            MyColorSlider.Color1 = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
```

Hope that helps, it's obviously a little basic.

Comment: thats a good example but can it be dynamic like if I want to have 6 widths based on user input

Comment: Easiest would be to create six rectangles with six widths and colors instead of three as above (or as many as the maximum your user can specify), and then just set the widths to zero if you want fewer rectangles showing.

Comment: okay thanks I think I know how to implement it. Using you example and a little bit tweaking i can do it.